# User Input Until Time Has Passed

Tags: perl

How can I get user input until a certain amount of time has passed (milliseconds, I'm using the `Time::HiRes` module) but if the time passes and there is no input then nothing happens. Specifically, I'm printing a question word by word until there's an interrupt from STDIN. To do this the program waits a small amount of time before continuing printing and prints the next word if there is no interrupt. How can I do this, or is the a better alternative. Thanks a bunch. My initial program looks something like this:

```
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;
$initial_time = gettimeofday();
until (gettimeofday() - $a == 200000) {
        ;
        if ([<]STDIN[>]) { #ignore the brackets
                print;
        }
}
```

Comment: Some solutions: Polling with Term::Readkey, IO::Select, making the handle non-blocking, interruption by signal

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `ualarm` function in [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html).

It works similarly to [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) so have a look there for an example of how to use it.

Here's a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Simple "Guess the Letter" game to demonstrate usage of the ualarm function
# in Time::HiRes

use Time::HiRes qw/ualarm/;

my @clues = ( "It comes after Q", "It comes before V", "It's not in RATTLE", 
    "It is in SNAKE", "Time's up!" ); 
my $correctAnswer = "S";

print "Guess the letter:\n";

for (my $i=0; $i < @clues; $i++) {
    my $input;

    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; 
        ualarm 200000;
        $input = <STDIN>;
        ualarm 0;
    };

    if ($@) {
        die unless $@ eq "alarm\n"; # propagate unexpected errors
        # timed out
    }
    else {
        # didn't
        chomp($input);
        if ($input eq $correctAnswer) {
            print "You win!\n";
            last;
        }
        else {
            print "Keep guessing!\n";
        }
    }

    print $clues[$i]."\n";
}

print "Game over man!\n";
```